# How to display images from file:///data/data/{package}/{folder}

Tags: cordova

How to display images from file:///data/data/{package}/{folder}

I tried displaying the image using

```
<img src="file:///data/data/com.testproject/images/file1.jpg" />
```

but it doesn't show up

Comment: Which operating system (guess android)?  What says adb (Log)? Are you sure about the URL? I think it will be a security-constraint or a wrong file-path).

Comment: thank you for your response, the OS is android, the log doesn't say much, i tried it again with an image i pushed to the emulator and its working, for some reason some downloaded file using FileSystem can't be displayed, on several test it works on emulator but not on actual device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OS is Android and you cant display some downloaded images (I guess from Facebook oder DropBox), you my not be able to display this files, because they are not stored with an file URL.

There are `media://` and `content://` Urls as well

There was a bug in some Phonegap Versions regarding the file-extension:

If you named your file .JPG (uppercase) they could not be loaded via file-api, the ug also appeared for some downloded files, because of the `content://media/files/123123` URLs (no extension in the URL)

And there was a bug (hopefully fixed yet):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2501

Answer (score 0):

If testproject is the name of your application then you will want to do this:

```
<img src="images/file1.jpg" />
```

Comment: thank you but it will take that from the assets, so it will not work